# SQL Server index question

Tags: sql-server, indexing

When creating an index for a specific query is it good practice to index all columns that are in the where clause and then have any columns selected in the "included columns" section?  Should I leave bit columns out of the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a classic "it depends". If you include them, then you are creating a covering index, which will be far more efficient but equally you will incur a penalty on row insertion, deletions and some updates.

You also pay a price on the disk space, so if you are going to include very wide columns on a large table, you are balancing the increase in storage overhead vs the performance gain.

All things being equal, a covering index is normally a good thing, but there are caveats such as the space and overhead on other operations to be mindful of.

Comment: On this particular database inserts/updates/deletions are only performed once per day in the middle of the night so I'm willing to take a hit on that performance.  Knowing that it seems like a covering index would be the way to go then?

Comment: Sounds more like a DW or Hybrid than a pure OLTP so a covering index is probably in your favour - but it really is a YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

It always depends. There are many factors at play: index size, columns selectivity, query frequency, updates rate etc. There is no generic rule to leve bit column add or to add them in, the answer is always specific to a particular question.

- [Index Design Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179560.aspx)
- [General Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191195.aspx)
- [Clustered Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639.aspx)
- [Nonclustered Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179325.aspx)